# Laravel - Call to a member function provides_service() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following error in my code which I'm having trouble figuring out. I would appreciate if anyone could help. What I am trying to do is add validation to the working hours that have been input by an employee. In my create appointment form I have input the following details;

[image]

however the following error is returned;

> Call to a member function provides_service() on null
>   in AppointmentsController.php (line 63)

I'm not sure why this is occurring as the data exists in my db;

[image]

AppointmentsController - store method

```
public function store(StoreAppointmentsRequest $request)

        $employee = \App\Employee::find($request->employee_id);
        $working_hours = \App\WorkingHour::where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)->whereDay('date', '=', date("d", strtotime($request->date)))->whereTime('start_time', '<=', date("H:i", strtotime("".$request->starting_hour.":".$request->starting_minute.":00")))->whereTime('finish_time', '>=', date("H:i", strtotime("".$request->finish_hour.":".$request->finish_minute.":00")))->get();

        if($employee->provides_service($request->service_id)) 
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors("This employee doesn't provide your selected service")->withInput();

        if($working_hours->isEmpty()) 
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors("This employee isn't working at your selected time")->withInput();

        $appointment = new Appointment;
        $appointment->client_id = $request->client_id;
        $appointment->employee_id = $request->employee_id;
        $appointment->start_time = "".$request->date." ".$request->starting_hour .":".$request->starting_minute.":00";
        $appointment->finish_time = "".$request->date." ".$request->finish_hour .":".$request->finish_minute.":00";
        $appointment->comments = $request->comments;
        $appointment->save();



        return redirect()->route('admin.appointments.index');
    }
```

Comment: Apparently `$employee` is null. You might to make sure that `employee_id` is correct and that it's returning a valid result before you try to use it.

Comment: thanks for this... but appears to be correct